# Efficient version of matlab's deconv in python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy, convolution

Is there an efficient implementation of [matlab's deconv](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/deconv.html) in python?

```
# Convolve
z=conv(x, y) 
# Deconvolve
y0=deconv(z, x)
# Hope y~=y0
```

(surprisingly, googling this bring no intresting results)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scipy and Numpy are pretty efficient for numerical calculations. Specifically, you can use [convolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html#scipy.signal.convolve) and [deconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.deconvolve.html#scipy.signal.deconvolve)

For an even faster implementation of convolve, also check out [fftconvolve](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html#scipy.signal.fftconvolve)

Comment: Is there an FFT-based deconvolve?

Comment: @endolith I don't think so, but [this discussion](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2011-August/030148.html) might help you, specifically the formula for Weiner deconvolution can be directly implemented using ffts and iffts